# Is Vertica's COPY atomic?

Tags: copy, vertica

Seems like a simple thing, but I can't seem to find it in the docs for [`COPY`](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Statements%7CCOPY%7C_____0).

Is Vertica's `COPY` atomic? If a data load is interrupted or somehow fails, does Vertica take care of the cleanup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vertica supports ANSI SQL-92 isolation levels with standard ACID properties. If a `COPY` is terminated, interrupted, or an error occurs, it will be rolled back.

> By default, HP Vertica uses the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level.
>
> The `COPY` command automatically commits itself and any current transaction (except when loading temporary tables). HP recommends that you `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` the current transaction before you use `COPY`. Please note that DDL statements are autocommitted.

[Documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Other/Transactions.htm)